# How to cast swiftyjson value if sometimes is detected as int and other as string

Tags: swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I am getting the login info using alamofire and swiftyjson

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters: newPost)
                .responseSwiftyJSON({ (request, response, json, error) in
```

in my post response i have the value

```
json["id_usuario"]
```

the problem is that, when the value is -1 or 0 (zero) it can be obtained as int
using

```
let idUser = json["id_usuario"].int
```

and example of the reponse with the value in -1

```
{
  "id_usuario" : -1
}
```

and the response when the value is greater than, a success login

```
{
  "estado" : "Jalisco",
  "plan_activo" : "0",
  "datos_registro_completos" : 1,
  "plan" : 0,
  "genero" : "H",
  "id_usuario_openpay" : "annvwl3didjylvex0wzh",
  "fb_id" : "10205386840402780",
  "email" : "steel.edward@hotmail.com",
  "postal_code" : "44630",
  "address" : "Nueva Escocia #1514 Interior 106",
  "nombres" : "Steel Edward",
  "app_mat" : "George",
  "app_pat" : "Vázquez",
  "ciudad" : "Guadalajara",
  "id_usuario" : "204",
  "admin" : "1",
  "phone_number" : "3334691505"
}
```

but if the value is greater than 0 returns a nil and only could be obtained as string

```
let idUser = json["id_usuario"].string
```

my final code works and looks like this

```
if let idUser = json["id_usuario"].int {
   if(idUser == -1) {
        //specific error from the server
   } else if(idUser == 0) {
        //another specific error from the server                            
   }
} else if let idUser = json["id_usuario"].string {
          if(idUser != "") {
             //success
          }
}
```

i would like to store the value always as Int and perform the validation using it, and to have a code like this

```
if(idUser == -1) {
  //specific error from the server
} else if(idUser == 0) {
  //another specific error from the server
} else if (idUser > 0) {
  //success
}
```

Comment: How is the data transmitted in the actual JSON as that makes no sense?

Comment: `but if the value is greater than 0 returns a nil and only could be obtained as string` This doesn't make much sense. Please show us examples of values bigger than 0 that are failing.

Comment: The response comes from PHP using json_encode from an Array

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = 0
if let num = json["id_usuario"].int {
    id = num
} else if let str = json["id_usuario"].string,
    let num = Int(str) {
    id = num
}
//
// do something with id, which is an Int value
```

if you own the server code, you are better to find a bug there ....

Answer (score 0):

This was my first solution not using Swifty-JSON

```
    let id_usuario_object:NSObject = jsonData.valueForKey("id_usuario") as! NSObject

    var id_usuario:Int

    if ( id_usuario_object.isKindOfClass(NSString) ) {
         let id_usuario_string:NSString = jsonData.valueForKey("id_usuario") as! NSString
         id_usuario = Int(id_usuario_string.intValue)
    } else {
         id_usuario = jsonData.valueForKey("id_usuario") as! NSInteger
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem resides in the JSON response from the PHP...

Before

```
echo json_encode( $results);
```

After

```
echo json_encode( $results, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK );
```